# Contamitacion de evento click en otro eventos click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo un problema en mi proyecto, estoy escuchando el evento click de una imagen llamada "mascara", condicionada por el color detectado donde el usuario haga click en codigo deberia ejecutar una u otra accion condicionada por el color al que halla hecho click el usuario.

**El problema**, es que al dar click la primera vez, la funcion se me replica para todos los demas eventos click que ejecute, si recargo la pagina y doy click en otro lugar me ejecuta el evento click correctamente pero este tambien se replica para los demas eventos click que ejecute

**Codigo donde esta el problema**

```
  if (hex == "#31c531") {

    var figura1 = document.getElementById("figura1");
    figura1.style.display = "block";

    img.addEventListener("click",funcion_click);


    function funcion_click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("FIGURA 1");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    }

    }

    else
    {

     var figura1 = document.getElementById("figura1");
    figura1.style.display = "none";

    }

    if (hex == "#0e378d") {

       var figura2 = document.getElementById("figura2");
    figura2.style.display = "block";
    //FIGURA 2

    img.addEventListener("click",funcion_click);


    function funcion_click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("FIGURA 2");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    }
    }
    else
    {

     var figura2 = document.getElementById("figura2");
    figura2.style.display = "none";

    }
    if (hex == "#b324c2") {

     var figura3 

= document.getElementById("figura3");
figura3.style.display = "block";


//FIGURA 3
  img.addEventListener("click",funcion_click);


function funcion_click(e) {
e.preventDefault();

alert("FIGURA 3");
e.stopImmediatePropagation();

}

}
else
{

 var figura3 = document.getElementById("figura3");
figura3.style.display = "none";

}
if (hex == "#d83232") {

 var figura4 = document.getElementById("figura4");
figura4.style.display = "block";

//FIGURA 4
img.addEventListener("click",funcion_click);
function funcion_click(e) {
e.preventDefault();

alert("FIGURA 4");
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
}
else
{
 var figura4 = document.getElementById("figura4");
figura4.style.display = "none";

}
```

[CODIGO COMPLETO EN CODE OPEN](https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/ZqxgMo?editors=1010)

Comment: pareciera que le estas agregando listeners en vez de reemplazarlos, no sería mas conveniente manejarlo con un map area polígono?

Comment: En este caso amigo, no puedo usar mapas de coordenadas, me lo pidieron explicablemente de esta forma y lo de las coordenadas no son una opcion

Comment: mas allá de la restricción `addEventListener` agrega un listener a la cadena de triggers, que se van a ejecutar todos en orden de inserción. probá con `img.onclick=function(ev){}`,